# Problem with converting Byte array to String

Tags: java, arrays, string, android-studio, encryption

The decryption method fails to convert the received byte array into a string

```
    public String decryptData(String data, SecretKeySpec key) throws Exception{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decodedValue = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decValue = cipher.doFinal(decodedValue);
    String outputData = new String(decValue, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    Log.d("Log byte:", decodedValue.toString());
    Log.d("Log byte:", decValue.toString());
    Log.d("Log str:", outputData);
}
```

Output logs:

```
D/Log byte:: [B@4b0fd32
D/Log byte:: [B@32d3a83
D/Log str::
```

cipher.doFinal() returns an empty array, i think that's why I'm getting an empty String value

Comment: If you direct want byte data into string then use this `String outputData = String.valueOf(decValue);`.

Comment: I want to get an initially encrypted string, the original text before encryption.
cipher.dofinal return 0 size array, i think there is a problem

Comment: `Log.d(java.util.Arrays.toString(decValue))` gives what?

Comment: Log.d("Log:", java.util.Arrays.toString(decValue)); -> D/Log :: []

Comment: Log.d("Log byte:", java.util.Arrays.toString(decodedValue)); -> D/Log byte:: [-94, 94, -91, -128, 106, 47, -128, -102, 38, -85, -124, 6, 75, -88, 83, -124]

Answer (score 0):

I am using this method for decryption with AES method.

```
 private final String characterEncoding = "UTF-8";
private final String cipherTransformation = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private final String aesEncryptionAlgorithm = "AES";

public String decrypt(String encryptedText, String key) throws KeyException, GeneralSecurityException, GeneralSecurityException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException {
        byte [] cipheredBytes = Base64.decode(encryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
        return new String (decrypt(cipheredBytes, keyBytes, keyBytes), characterEncoding);
    }
```